# Long bottom figure float disappears in twocolumn article with stfloats

Tags: floats

This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{stfloats}
\begin{document}
Figure \ref{figure}
\begin{figure}%[b]
    \vspace*{15\baselineskip}
    \caption{This is the figure!}
    \label{figure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

You will note that the compiled document does not show the figure float as soon as you uncomment `[b]`. Removing `stfloats`, or changing `[b]` to something else, or changing `15` to `10`, makes the float re-appear, so this must be a very special case. Still, is this known or expected from `stfloats`? Or is this my fault in doing things the wrong way?

Note that this is fairly well reduced from the original MWE: no `IEEEtran`, no `graphicx`, no `subfloat`, no `\includegraphics`, no `\subfloat`.

I am using newest MiKTeX on Windows with `pdflatex`, which creates a letter-paper sized pdf file. My version of `sttools` (which provides `stfloats`) is 1.8, dated 2016-02-12 15:45:58. `stfloats.sty` has

```
\ProvidesPackage{stfloats}
    [2016/02/08 v2.0 Improve float mechanism and baselineskip settings]
```

I could not reproduce the error on sharelatex.com, which uses

```
Package: stfloats 2012/05/29 v1.1 Improve float mechanism and baselineskip settings
```

Comment: I see the images. Try scaling the images with `\includegraphics[width=<width>]{<image>}`?

Comment: IEEEtranj document class is intended for two column articles ... so if you say`\subfloat[]{\includegraphics[width=\columnwidth]{example-image}}` you will see images :-) or change `{figure}` to `{figure*}`

Comment: with `{figure*}` images appear on the second page (if you comment package `mwe`, which is not neccessary for this test ...)! if not, than you have something different/broken as other have. I have MikTeX, recent version and your NWE works as expected.

Comment: You also need to change figure option from `b` to `htb` ... or use `!b`

Comment: This should explain one of LaTeX gurus ... why this problem appear only with placement `b` and not at `t` or `h` or any combination of them, is over my knowledge. I always use position options as `htbp` and newer have problem you find.

Comment: The disparition happens somewhere between `11.7\baselineskip` and `11.8\baselineskip`. If I keep the 11.8 factor and compile with TL2014, the figure appears at the end (I added some `\lipsum` paragraphs); from TL2015 onward it disappears. So, apparently the bug fix meant to correct the bad placement turned out into a different bug.

Comment: If I add `\RequirePackage[2014/01/01]{latexrelease}` at the top, the float appears at the end. So, sorry, it's a bug in `stfloats`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can confirm that `stfloats` contains a bug with latest `latexrelease`.
The bugfix version (2016-06-28 v3.2) is just uploaded to the CTAN as part of `sttools` bundle (2016-06-28 v1.9).

By the way, keep in mind that maximum proportion (as a decimal number) of a text page or column that can be occupied by floats at the bottom `\bottomfraction` is .3, as at the top `\topfraction` it is .7

Comment: Thanks for fixing the bug with disappearing floats. Also, that comment about `\topfraction` and `\bottomfraction` is really helpful in understanding why the he** I was not able to position my floats `[b]`, even though that exact position was possible using `[p]` (that was irrespective of `stfloats`). Thanks again!

Comment: `[p]` should be `[h]` in the above  comment...